# Updating a DataFrame column using logical comparison

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Based on the suggestions below, I have merged the dataframes into a single DF. Hence changed the title as well. Following is a screen capture of my merged dataframe :
[image]

I now need to compare Adj Close with the rest of the columns to exactly know where it lies - e.g. is it between PP and R1, R1 and R2, R2 and R3 etc. Based on this, I need to create a new Status column, which would have the relevant statuses. I wrote function as below

```
def check_status(merged):
if merged['Adj Close'] < merged['R3']:
    merged['Status'] = 'Breached R3'
elif merged['R3'] < merged['Adj Close'] < merged['R2']:
    merged['Status'] = 'Breached R2'
elif merged['R2'] < merged['Adj Close'] < merged['R1']:
    merged['Status'] = 'Breached R1'
elif merged['R1'] < merged['Adj Close'] < merged['PP']:
    merged['Status'] = 'Breached PP on lower side'
elif merged['PP'] < merged['Adj Close'] < merged['S1']:
    merged['Status'] = 'Breached PP on higher side'
elif merged['S1'] < merged['Adj Close'] < merged['S2']:
    merged['Status'] = 'Breached S1'
elif merged['S2'] < merged['Adj Close'] < merged['S3']:
    merged['Status'] = 'Breached S2'
else:
    merged['Status'] = 'Breached S3'
return merged
```

This gives an error as below :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Next I tried with np.where(). The code snippet is below :

```
merged['Status'] = np.where(merged['Adj Close'] < merged['R3'], 'Breached R3', merged['Adj Close'])
merged['Status'] = np.where(merged['R2'] < merged['Adj Close'] < merged['R1'], 'Breached R1', merged['Adj Close'])
merged['Status'] = np.where(merged['R1'] < merged['Adj Close'] < merged['PP'], 'Breached PP on lower side', merged['Adj Close'])
merged['Status'] = np.where(merged['PP'] < merged['Adj Close'] < merged['S1'], 'Breached PP on higher side', merged['Adj Close'])
merged['Status'] = np.where(merged['S1'] < merged['Adj Close'] < merged['S2'], 'Breached S1', merged['Adj Close'])
merged['Status'] = np.where(merged['S2'] < merged['Adj Close'] < merged['S3'], 'Breached S2', merged['Adj Close'])
merged['Status'] = np.where(merged['S3'] < merged['Adj Close'], 'Breached S3', merged['Adj Close'])
```

However, I get the same error.

What options do I have to get the Status column updated as above ?

I have a large DF, so performance could be a consideration.

Comment: Will you please a sample of your dataframe?

Comment: Use function `join` to merge the dfs on the index, or `merge` to merge them on columns.

Comment: I rolled back your latest edits; you are more than welcome to post your solution as an answer (and accept it once you can, to _actually_ mark this as resolved), but your question should remain strictly a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.select` with whole dataframe.

```
conditions = [
    df['Adj Close'] < df['R3'],
    (df['R2'] < df['Adj Close']) & (df['Adj Close'] < df['R1']),
    (df['R1'] < df['Adj Close']) & (df['Adj Close'] < df['PP']),
    (df['PP'] < df['Adj Close']) & (df['Adj Close'] < df['S1']),
    (df['S1'] < df['Adj Close']) & (df['Adj Close'] < df['S2']),
    (df['S2'] < df['Adj Close']) & (df['Adj Close'] < df['S3']),
    df['S3'] < df['Adj Close']
]

values = [
    'Breached R3',
    'Breached R1',
    'Breached PP on lower side',
    'Breached PP on higher side',
    'Breached S1',
    'Breached S2',
    'Breached S3'
]

df['Status'] = np.select(conditions, values, df['Adj Close'])
```

This will significantly speed up your program @Sachin

Comment: @Sachin Check this answer. It will help achieve vectorization and significantly speed up the code.

Comment: Excellent !!! This is exactly what I was looking for !!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using `np.where()` in a `for` loop:

```
for i in merged:
    merged['Status'] = np.where(merged['Adj Close'] > merged['R3'], 'Breached R3', merged['Status'])
    merged['Status'] = np.where(np.logical_and(merged['R3'] > merged['Adj Close'], merged['Adj Close'] > merged['R2']), 'Breached R2', merged['Status'])
    merged['Status'] = np.where(np.logical_and(merged['R2'] > merged['Adj Close'], merged['Adj Close'] > merged['R1']), 'Breached R1', merged['Status'])
    merged['Status'] = np.where(np.logical_and(merged['R1'] > merged['Adj Close'], merged['Adj Close'] > merged['PP']), 'Breached PP on higher side', merged['Status'])
    merged['Status'] = np.where(np.logical_and(merged['PP'] > merged['Adj Close'], merged['Adj Close'] > merged['S1']), 'Breached PP onn lower side', merged['Status'])
    merged['Status'] = np.where(np.logical_and(merged['S1'] > merged['Adj Close'], merged['Adj Close'] > merged['S2']), 'Breached S1', merged['Status'])
    merged['Status'] = np.where(np.logical_and(merged['S2'] > merged['Adj Close'], merged['Adj Close'] > merged['S3']), 'Breached S2', merged['Status'])
    merged['Status'] = np.where(merged['S3'] > merged['Adj Close'] , 'Breached S3', merged['Status'])
```

Thanks a lot for all the suggestions.